# Как пользоватся типом данных BOOLEAN в SELECT запросе?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Имеется PL/SQL функциия с типом данных `BOOLEAN` как параметр:

```
function get_something(name in varchar2, ignore_notfound in boolean);
```

Эта функция часть инструментов от сторонних разработчиков и я не могу её менять.

Хотелось  бы использовать эту функцию в SELECT запросе:

```
 select get_something('NAME', TRUE) from dual;
```

Но так не работает, получаю ошибку:

> ORA-00904: "TRUE": invalid identifier

Как понимаю, кючевое слово `TRUE` не распознаётся.

Как же сделать чтобы оно работало?

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/1465405/6571020

Comment: Интересно - а если попробовать `select get_something('NAME', 1) from dual` - отработает ли правильно?

Comment: @MaxU Попробовать конечно можно, только ничего не получится, типы boolean и number даже в pl/sql несовместимы ;)

Comment: я понадеялся на неявное преобразование типов...

Answer (score 3):

Можно сделать обёрточную функцию, например:

```
function get_something (name in varchar2, ignore_notfound in varchar2) return varchar2 is
begin
    return get_something (name, (upper(ignore_notfound) = 'TRUE'));
end;
```

Затем вызывать её так:

```
select get_something ('Name', 'true') from dual;
```

Решите, какие значения для `ignore_notfound` больше подходят.
Я предположил, что `'TRUE'` или `'true'` означает `TRUE`, всё остальное - `FALSE`.

<sub>Источник [@TonyAndrews](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1465430/6571020)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Всё просто, вместо `TRUE` пишешь `1 = 1`, соответственно `FALSE` `1 != 1`